# Start command from run dialogue with elevated privilages keyboard shortcut

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, run-dialog, elevated

In windows 7 you can start applications as admin by searching in the start menu and then pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Is a similar shortcut available for the Run Window (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>)?

Comment: The same command worked for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has been asked before in 2010.

Unfortunately the result "no possible short-cut" applies even today. Run cannot elevate programs to admin level. It can only elevate the cmd via:

```
runas /user:admin "cmd"
```

The workaround is to manually set the program(s) to run as admin through the properties menu.

source: link: [Have Windows "Run" dialog run as Admin?](https://superuser.com/questions/203068/have-windows-run-dialog-run-as-admin)

Comment: Yes it does, in the search charm menu, type in a program e.g 'snip' and then press CTRL+ALT+ENTER

Comment: In that case, you can maybe mark as duplicate?
I didn't find one earlier, but the absence of evidence isn't the evidence of absence ;)

Comment: @BorisCallens Second that. I would look around for a program solution every so often.

Comment: @Ramhound Boris is talking about the run menu not the charm bar.. you know WINKEY+R? I stand correct in my solution.

Comment: @Pathfinder I aplogize I was reading the question on a phone, I missed part of the question.

Comment: @Ramhound Apology accepted. Boris, Question is marked as duplicate.